# Correct way to wait until ElasticLoadBalancingv2 is ready in Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cloud, boto3

I use the python3 library, boto3, to create a ElasticLoadBalancingv2 and want to wait until some conditions such as running or terminated.

I know it should use the `Waiter` to wait for it like the `EC2` class, it has

`waiter = ec2_client.get_waiter('instance_running')`

then

`waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance_id])`

But I cannot find any documents about waiter in the `ElasticLoadBalancingv2` to do such things.

It only has `get_waiter(waiter_name)` but no any information about `waiter_name`.

How do I solve it? what I think now is use `describe` to get its `status` in a `while` loop, but I don't know it is a good way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `waiter_names` attribute on the client to check for available waiters:

```
elbclient = boto3.client('elbv2', region_name='us-east-1')
print elbclient.waiter_names
```

Then you use can use the waiters but they have different keyword arguments than the ELB classic waiters, e.g. LoadBalancerArns, Names, Marker, PageSize:

```
waiter = elbclient.get_waiter('load_balancer_available')
```

Comment: I use the python3 but print(elbclient.waiter_names) shows `empty list`

Comment: And waiter = elbclient.get_waiter('load_balancer_available') shows `Waiter does not exist: load_balancer_available`

Comment: Maybe you need to update your boto3 and botocore packages. I was missing some features on the elbclassic modules with older versions. Something like `pip install --upgrade boto3 botocore`

Comment: It's not a matter of updating the package. The `load_balancer_available` waiter is available in the `elbv2` client but not in `elb`.